# Как достать два минимальных из множества в python?

Tags: python

Задача такая: нужна достать буквы, которые встречаются в тексте только 1 раз. Я пробовал использовать min, но он достает только одно значение и больше вариантов нет.

```
b = 'moonmens'
s = {}
m = ''
for i in b:
if i in s:
    s[i] += 1
if i not in s:
    s.setdefault(i, 1)
```

Comment: Если больше вариантов нет, то что за код Вы тогда привели? В нём отлично считается количество каждой буквы. Осталось лишь пройтись по словарю и достать те ключи, значения которых равны единице.

Comment: Так я понимаю, как  он работает, ибо написан мной же. Я не понимаю, как достать как раз эти ключи.

Comment: `dict.items()` возвращает множество кортежей типа `(ключ, значение)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

код для вывода букв которые встречаются минимальное число раз (даже если их больше 1):

```
text = "moonmens"

# получить уникальные буквы
letters = set(text)

# подсчитать кол-во уникальных букв в тексте
counts = [(letter, text.count(letter)) for letter in letters]

# отсортировать список
counts.sort(key=lambda obj: obj[1])

# вывести буквы с минимальным кол-вом повторений
count = counts[0][1]
res = [obj[0] for obj in counts if obj[1] == count]

print(*res)
```

код для ситуации с единократным встречанием буквы в тексте:

```
res = [letter for letter in text if text.count(letter) == 1]

print(*res)
```

Answer (score 2):

*достать буквы, которые встречаются в тексте только 1 раз.*

```
b = 'moonmens'
for c in set(b):
    if b.count(c)==1:
        print (c)
```

Результат:

```
e
s
```

Answer (score 2):

Примените класс `Counter` из стандартного модуля `collections` — он *автоматически вычислит количества появлений всякой буквы* в форме подобной словарю.

Затем выберите только буквы с количеством `1`:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(b)       # для b == 'moonmens': {'m': 2, 'o': 2, 'n': 2, 'e': 1, 's': 1}
for char in counter:
    if counter[char] == 1:
        print(char)
```

Answer (score 1):

как вариант:

```
b = 'moonmens'
print(*[ i for i in b if b.count(i) == 1], sep='\n')
```